# Why imperative code does not update when the inputs change?

Tags: shiny

I'm learning Rshiny, i came through this block of code in which the author said that x1 and x2 are calculated only 1 time at the beginning of the Shiny session, not every time one of the inputs was updated.

It is quite strange as x1 and x2 are clearly function of the variables of input, so it should be updated whenever the inputs changed, right ? Could you help me to explain it ? Thank you very much for your help!

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x1 <- rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1)
  x2 <- rnorm(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2)

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    freqpoly(x1, x2, binwidth = input$binwidth, xlim = input$range)
  }, res = 96)

  output$ttest <- renderText({
    t_test(x1, x2)
  })
}
```

Comment: You may want to recheck the example. The code you provided would error. `input$n1` and `input$n2` can only be evaluated inside a reactive expression like within `renderPlot` or `renderText`